# Access MainActivity.class from Fragment throw an error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This my fragment code

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.encrypt_fragment, container, false);

    btn_selectin = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_import);
    btn_encrypt = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_encrypt);

    btn_selectin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mainActivity.test();
        }
    });

    btn_encrypt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mainActivity.test1();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

I want access MainActivity.class method

```
    public void test(){
       textview = 1;
       showFileChooser();
}

    private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Process"), FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This code will instance file explorer

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: com.plane.fusionencryp, PID: 7551
>                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.plane.fusionencryp/com.plane.fusionencryp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #109: Binary XML file line #109: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: replace `mainActivity.test();` to `((MainActivity)getActivity()).test();`

Comment: You can not use an activity like that. If the fragment is contained in the main activity you can call getActivity() from the fragment and have an instance of the activity. Otherwise either you make that method public and static to acces it (this is not such a good idea but it works) or you extract in in an Utils class and call it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is creating a new instance of the `MainActivity Class`
Which is a wrong way of getting the activity instance.

Here is your problem.

`final MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();`
and 
`mainActivity.test();`

But what you want is the instance of the MainActivity which is holding that fragment. So in the fragment, you can do like this.

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).test();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the parent activity by casting.

```
((MainAcitivty)getActivity).test()
```

Remember: MainActivity should be your fragment parent activity